# pgfplots: Clipping Everything Outside a Specific Area

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I want to add information to each column of a histogram. `every node near coord` is probably the best approach. It works well with bar plots but not with the histogram:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar interval,
xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick,
% Code to generate labels
nodes near coords={
\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}
},
every node near coord/.style={
anchor=south,xshift=9mm,
},
%
]
\addplot+[hist={bins=3}]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I used `every node near coord/.style` to shift the labels.

The **problem** is that I have **four labels** for **three columns/bars**:

[image]

I addition I would like to **center the labels**. A workaround will be a manual adjustment (`every node near coord/.style`) just like in the shown example.

**Update**

Maybe **clipping** is a possibility. Is there a way to clip the labels (in this case the 7 in the right) away?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: I think this is actually a bug: `nodes near coords` should not generate the last item at all for `ybar interval`.

Comment: The same is probably true for the missing shift. I noted both on the todo list for `pgfplots` (i.e. I accept them as bug/feature requests).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The necessary xshift for the `nodes near coords` labels can be calculated from the `width` of the axis, the number of `bins` and the value of `enlarge x limits` (defined in the new macro `\enlargexlimits`).

```
nodes near coords*/.add code={}{\tikzset{every node/.append style={xshift={
  (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}-45pt) % every plot is 45pt smaller then the width
  /(1+2*\enlargexlimits) % correction for enlarge x limits
  /\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/hist/bins} % number of bins
  /2% shift only half of bin width
}}}},
```

If you want clipping all stuff right of the plot box you can fill this area with your page color and recalculate the bounding box of the whole plot.

Therefore I define a macro

```
\newcommand\clipright[1][white]{
  \fill[#1](current axis.south east)rectangle(current axis.north-|current axis.outer east);
  \pgfresetboundingbox
  \useasboundingbox(current axis.outer south west)rectangle(current axis.outer north-|current axis.east);
}
```

and a second macro to show the resulting boundig box of the plot

```
\newcommand\showbb{
  \draw[red,dashed](current bounding box.south west)rectangle(current bounding box.north east);
}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % notice: version 1.10 or later is needed

\newcommand*\enlargexlimits{.1} % default value for enlarge x limits 

\pgfplotsset{%
  hist nodes near coords/.style={%
    nodes near coords*/.add code={}{\tikzset{every node/.append style={xshift={
      (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}-45pt) % every plot is 45pt smaller then the width
      /(1+2*\enlargexlimits) % correction for enlarge x limits
      /\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/hist/bins} % number of bins
      /2% shift only half of bin width
    }}}},
    nodes near coords={%
      \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}
    }}
}

\newcommand\clipright[1][white]{
  \fill[#1](current axis.south east)rectangle(current axis.north-|current axis.outer east);
  \pgfresetboundingbox
  \useasboundingbox(current axis.outer south west)rectangle(current axis.outer north-|current axis.east);
}

\newcommand\showbb{
  \draw[red,dashed](current bounding box.south west)rectangle(current bounding box.north east);
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
    ybar interval,
    xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick,
    enlarge x limits=\enlargexlimits
  ]
    \addplot+[hist={bins=3},hist nodes near coords]
      table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
      data\\
      1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
      7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
    };
  \end{axis}
  \clipright
  \showbb
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But there will be a problem if you increase the number of bins. Here is the result of `bin=9`:

[image]

To solve this you can decrease the `enlarge x limits` by redefining the macro `\enlargexlimits`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\enlargexlimits{0.04} % changing the value of `enlarge x limits`
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar interval,
    xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick,
    enlarge x limits=\enlargexlimits
  ]
```

Then you will get

[image]

Or with `\def\enlargexlimits{0}` you will get

[image]

Note: the labels are again automatically centered.

---

**My former suggestion**

To supress the additional label the `pgfmath` if-then-else function is used. The syntax is `x ? y : z` meaning " if *x* then *y* else *z* "

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} % notice: version 1.10 or later is needed

\newcommand*\NNC{\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}}
\newcommand*\enlargexlimits{.1} % default value for enlarge x limits 

\pgfplotsset{%
  hist nodes near coords/.style={%
    nodes near coords*/.add code={}{\tikzset{every node/.append style={xshift={
      (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}-45pt) % every plot is 45pt smaller then the width
      /(1+2*\enlargexlimits) % correction for enlarge x limits
      /\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/hist/bins} % number of bins
      /2% shift only half of bin width
    }}}},
    nodes near coords={% 
      \pgfmathparse{
        \pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}<#1*\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/hist/data max}?%
          "\noexpand\NNC"%  if true print nodes near coords
          :% if false suppress the additional node near coords
      }\pgfmathresult%
    }},
  hist nodes near coords/.default={0.9}% if you set data max explicitly it will be 1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar interval,
    xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick,
    enlarge x limits=\enlargexlimits
  ]
    \addplot+[hist={bins=3},hist nodes near coords]
      table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
      data\\
      1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
      7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar interval,
    xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick,
    enlarge x limits=\enlargexlimits
  ]
    \addplot+[hist={bins=2},hist nodes near coords]
      table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
      data\\
      1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
      7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
    };
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What's the main idea? Some kinf of if-then-else?

Comment: Yes, I use a `pgfmath` if-then-else function with syntax `x ? y : z` meaning " if *x* then *y* else *z* "

Comment: Ok. Thanks! (Danke :) I want to wait a bit - maybe another solution is also possible.

Comment: No problem, it would be fine if there is another and possible better solution. (In the manual (version 1.10) you can read on page 108: "Currently nodes near coords does not work satisfactorily for ybar interval or xbar interval, sorry.")

Comment: Didn't see that in the manual - thanks for the hint.

Comment: Hello. Maybe clipping would help. So the '7' is clipped off. I tried to search the forum but no luck.

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Your if-then solution worked fine to me. You could propose a solution for this bug on the package. Regards.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative is the use of `clip` command.

Sine the OP does not provide `data point/y` infomation, this solution uses home-made substitutes for demonstration purpose. The frame in the sectiond image is again for demonstration whch can be adjusted in the `clip` command. Remove `preaction=draw` in the `clip` option to remove the frame. Note `clip=false` is required in the solution.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,varwidth]{standalone}%{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usetikzlibrary{pgfplots.statistics}

\begin{document}

Before:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar interval,
clip=false,
xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick,
% Code to generate labels
%nodes near coords={
%\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}
%},
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
every node near coord/.style={
anchor=south,xshift=9mm,
},
%
]
\begin{scope}
\addplot+[hist={bins=3}]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
};
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

After:

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
ybar interval,
clip=false,
xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick,
% Code to generate labels
%nodes near coords={
%\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}
%},
nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
every node near coord/.style={
anchor=south,xshift=9mm,
},
%
]
\begin{scope}
\clip[preaction=draw] (axis cs: -1,-0.1) rectangle (axis cs:11,8);  % remove preaction=draw to remove the frame
\addplot+[hist={bins=3}]
table[row sep=\\,y index=0] {
data\\
1\\ 2\\ 1\\ 5\\ 4\\ 10\\
7\\ 10\\ 9\\ 8\\ 9\\ 9\\
};
\end{scope}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Which version of `pgfplots` do you have? Your code works for me if I install version 1.8 in my local tree. But it does not work if I use version 1.9 or 1.10 even if I say `compat=1.8`.

Comment: Indeed, mine is 1.8.

Comment: That is also the reason why `nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}}}` does not work for you. To get the abundances automatically version 1.10 is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. So the key is **scope** and the **clip** command?!

Comment: Yes, indeed for pgfplots version 1.8.

Comment: @Jesse: And what about the newest version of pgfplots? Does ist still work there?

Comment: No, I am afraid not. I did tried it. Further your code does not work for version 1.8. So IMHO there is a backward/forward compatibility between these two versions. I also notice that the other answer requires 1.10 or later. With that informed, I keep two versions.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. It's more complicated than I thought.

Comment: I accepted the other answer but both are good. Can't decide. Thanks! The question is really difficult and depending from the pgfplots version. Damn.

Comment: Perfect. Your are nice.