# Histogram and nodes near coords

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart, nodes-near-coords

When using `pgfplots`'s `hist` in combination with `nodes near coords`, the nodes are misplaced on the edges of the bars and the last node is shown twice.

Is this a bug or is `nodes near coords` not meant to be used with `hist`?

## Issue:

[image: Issue]

## MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.52000000e+02
4.48000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
3.88000000e+02
3.32000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
3.20000000e+02
3.52000000e+02
3.28000000e+02
4.32000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.04000000e+02
4.52000000e+02
1.20000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
1.80000000e+02
4.48000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
3.24000000e+02
3.52000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
2.32000000e+02
3.76000000e+02
3.48000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
3.96000000e+02
2.56000000e+02
3.96000000e+02
4.16000000e+02
4.44000000e+02
4.52000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
2.84000000e+02
4.36000000e+02
4.16000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
2.64000000e+02
1.64000000e+02
4.24000000e+02
4.48000000e+02
4.44000000e+02
4.52000000e+02
3.92000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
2.48000000e+02
4.36000000e+02
2.44000000e+02
4.48000000e+02
1.60000000e+02
4.48000000e+02
4.48000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
2.44000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
3.64000000e+02
4.04000000e+02
4.40000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.32000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.48000000e+02
1.76000000e+02
4.36000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.44000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.36000000e+02
4.48000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
1.76000000e+02
4.44000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
2.72000000e+02
4.04000000e+02
4.20000000e+02
4.48000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
4.48000000e+02
4.60000000e+02
2.64000000e+02
1.72000000e+02
4.08000000e+02
2.04000000e+02
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[%
    ybar interval,
    xticklabel=\pgfmathprintnumber\tick--\pgfmathprintnumber\nexttick,
    x tick label style={font=\footnotesize,inner sep=0pt,rotate=90,anchor=east,},
    nodes near coords,
  ]

    \addplot+[hist={bins=10},] table[y index=0,] {data.dat};
  \end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: See [pgfplots: Clipping Everything Outside a Specific Area](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/181061/43317). And see  the manual (version 1.10), page 108: "Currently nodes near coords does not work satisfactorily for ybar interval or xbar interval, sorry."

Comment: @esdd Ah – I was looking for listed issues in the histogram section of the manual. You are absolutely right. Thanks. Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept it if no one provides a hack-y solution. `:-)`

Comment: I have added a link to a similar question in my first comment. There are two answers.

Comment: @esdd That's great! Thanks. I'll delete the question soon since it is a duplicate.

Comment: Might as well mark it as duplicate instead since other people may be searching for these terms.