# Adding number of data within the interval in a histogram

Tags: pgfplots, histogram

I have a set of random data. I could easily make a histogram in Mathematica as
[image]
Then I tried to replot this histogram in latex using the `pgfplots` package. But I only got
[image]
The important thing that was lost in this plot is the number of data within each bar. I don't know how can I do that. I need help to

1. place those numbers on each bar
2. insert more bars as it was made in the Mathematica.

The data file can be downloaded from [here](https://ufile.io/kv0i6lys) and here is my latex code for the histogram

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[small,ymin=0,title=\texttt{Histogram}]
        \addplot [
        hist,
        fill=orange!75,
        draw=orange!50!black]
        table [y index=0] {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

> place those numbers on each bar

can be achieved by

```
nodes near coords
```

> insert more bars as it was made in the Mathematica.

can be achieved by

```
hist={bins=25}
```

or any other number you want.

I took the liberty to enlarge the histogram so the numbers would fit.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=17cm,compat=1.17}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=0,title=\texttt{Histogram}]
        \addplot [
        hist={bins=25},
        nodes near coords,
        fill=orange!75,
        draw=orange!50!black]
        table [y index=0] {data.dat};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Hasan_Zakeri, Thanks for your answer.
how shall I remove the last number?
As is seen, the last one is redundant.

Comment: See 
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531470/problem-in-creating-a-histogram-having-number-of-occurrence-the-top-of-each-bar